# Substitute ./ and ../ directories by actual names

Tags: shell-script

I have a script which finds files in the directory specified by user.

```
#!/bin/bash

# make sure about the correct input
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: ./script_name.sh    path/to/directory"
else
    DIR=$1
    if [ $DIR = '.' ]
    then 
        echo "Find files in the directory $PWD"
    else  
        echo "Find files in the directory $DIR"
    fi

    find $DIR -type f -exec basename {} \; 
fi
```

if I input

```
$ ./script_name.sh .
```

script gives me correct substitution ./ to $PWD and shows (for example)

```
$ Find files in the directory /root/scripts
```

But I can't make a decision **how to substitute ../ to the name of the directory**  immediately above in the hierarchy.  If I input

```
$ ./script_name.sh ..
```

script gives me the output

```
$ Find files in the directory ..
```

Does anybody know how to substitute ../ to the actual name of the directory?

Comment: Try the `realpath` command if it is available.

Comment: @Bodo realpath works good in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNU coreutils has the [`realpath` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) that does just that.

```
/tmp/a$ realpath ..
/tmp
```

Though note that if the path contains symlinks, it will also resolve those:

```
/tmp/b/c$ realpath ..
/tmp/x/y
```

(Here, `/tmp/b` was a symlink to `/tmp/x/y/`)

This may be different from what the shell does with `cd ..`. E.g. `cd ../..` from `/tmp/b/c` in Bash shows the new path as `/tmp/`, not as `/tmp/x`.

Comment: `readlink` would be another alternative.

Comment: @twalberg `readlink` only resolves symlinks and not entries like `.` or `..`, which were the point of the question. `readlink .` results in an error (returns status code 1).

Comment: @JoL Try `readlink -f .`

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas:

```
parent="$(dirname "$(pwd)")"

parent="$(
   cd ..
   pwd
)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first `cd` to `..` and then use the `$PWD`.